# Repairing GRUB dual boot Kali and Windows system from "grub rescue>" prompt

Tags: grub, kali-linux, bootrepair, rescue

I resized the partition on my dual boot system (Windows and Kali Linux) and now it is booting with the `grub rescue>` prompt.

I am able to get from there to the `grub>` prompt using:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
set prefix=(hd0,msdos1) 
insmod normal 
normal
```

Note that msdos1 is my first partition (Windows).

But from the `grub>` prompt I can't go any further because it doesn't recognise `initrd` and Linux commands.

Comment: I can now get into my grub multiboot menu and boot into either os but on reboot it still goes into grub rescue> prompt. How do i repair that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make bootable USB or CD of linux (Ubuntu/Debian) and do the simplest thing in world.
Use package `boot-repair`. It should help like charm.

It's short copy-paste instruction to install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Regards,

Comment: i don't have the option of usb cd repair disk. I have full access to the system now.

Comment: I can't read first sentence. I mean `boot-repair` package - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: isn't there some way to repair the grub from the terminal?

Comment: `boot-repair` can be used by CLI

Comment: how do i install it from the terminal?

Comment: I just give you simplest tool - I can explain more widely about "on my own" but why if reconfiguration of grub can be done so simple or I will give you link if you want to do it manually https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7

Comment: You install it from terminal like any other app > adding repo > update > install

Comment: Happy that's work for you :)
Cheers