# Dual boot with Grub Ubuntu / Win 10 no longer available with Win10 Ver 1803 update

Tags: boot, grub, windows-10-upgrade, mbr, ubuntu-16.04

Dual boot with Grub Ubuntu 16.04 / Win 10 broke when Win 10 automatically updated to Version 1803 in August, 2018. Windows overwrote the Master Boot Record and the Grub menu has disappeared. Ubuntu HDD partition still exists. How do I repair the MBR, retain Grub, boot Ubuntu 2nd without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure the thing is about MBR? MBR exists in Legacy/BIOS installations only. Any computer from the this decade is likely to be UEFI, not BIOS.

Comment: there are tons of tutorials on google. Just boot a live Linux distro and run grub-install [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/253474), [How to reinstall grub](https://askubuntu.com/q/493612/253474)

Comment: @phuclv Correct. However, if the system is UEFI then the user just need to change the bootloader back to Ubuntu. I believe the OP described the problem correctly but may be misinterpreting what happened.

Comment: [Cross-posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298813/dual-boot-with-grub-ubuntu-win-10-no-longer-available-with-win10-ver-1803-upda), but on topic here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repairing GRUB dual boot Kali and Windows system from "grub rescue>" prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/1338433/repairing-grub-dual-boot-kali-and-windows-system-from-grub-rescue-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution in my case was to use the free Boot-Repair software by following the advice at https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Starting in a Windows 10 Version 1803 environment, I used Rufus to create a bootable USB Drive containing the Boot-Repair-Disk iso file.

- Can recover access to Windows (XP, Vista, Windows7, Windows8, Windows10).
- Can recover access to Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, OpenSuse, ArchLinux.
- Can recover access to any OS (Windows, MacOS, Linux..) if your PC contains Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, OpenSuse, ArchLinux, or derivative.

The original post making me aware of Boot-Repair came from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Thank you @GabrihelaGarcia @phuclv